# 2d circular collision reaction in Node.js

Tags: node.js, 2d, collision

I'm making a simple 2d game. There are entities, which are players and trees.

When the game is started, some trees are created and placed randomly.

When someone joins the game, a player entity is created.

Each entity looks like that:

```
type: "tree" | "player",
position: {
  x: float,
  y: float
},
collisionRadius: int,
...otherAttributes
```

The player can move; and what I'd like is that when it collides with a tree, or another player, it reacts.

I'm checking if two entities are colliding using this:

```js
function collides(
  p1,
  p2
) {
  const dx = p1.position.x - p2.position.x;
  const dy = p1.position.y - p2.position.y;
  const distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

  if (distance < p1.collisionRadius + p2.collisionRadius) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

And we can use it that way:

```js
const player = new Player();

// player.type -> "player"
// player.position.x -> 8965.9
// player.position.y -> 535.1
// player.collisionRadius -> 37

const tree = new Tree();

// tree.type -> "tree"
// tree.position.x -> 8003.0
// tree.position.y -> 535.1
// tree.collisionRadius -> 45

// After the player moves a bit

// tree.position.x -> 8003.0
// player.position.x -> 7993.5

collides(tree, player); // true
```

If the tree and the player collides, the player should be pushed to the sides of the tree.
Tho, if two players collides, the one moving should be pushed to the sides of the other one, but the other one should be pushed back. (as it is not static like a tree)

How can I do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What I would do is give each entity a `velocity: { x: float, y: float }` property, and at each collision, compare the velocities and types of the two entities. If one is a player and the other a tree, set the position of the player to be next to the tree. If both are players, set the position of the player with the greater velocity to be next to the other player.

Comment: What would `velocity.x` and `velocity.y` equal to?